# How to add a single additional edge loop without a triangle

Tags: faces, edges, topology

I'm trying to add some geometry so that there is an additional face loop/edge, such as the example on the right (6 edges on bottom, 7 on top).  However, this introduces a triangle.  Is there a way to do this with quads, or with a triangle that doesn't interfere somehow? The middle example adds two additional edges (6 on bottom, 8 on top), but keeps the face loops functional.
[image: Adding geometry examples]

If it is only possible to do with a triangle, is there a better method to maintain better face/edge loops and subsurf?

Comment: http://topologyguides.com/post/129783341675/redirecting-edge-flows-within-a-mesh

Comment: That site is wicked!

Answer (score 1):

To change the flow its pretty straightforward. There are 3 methods that I use but here is the most simple:

Select the path of edges you want the flow to follow:

[image]

Once you have the path just bevel it (ctrl b).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edited with a longer answer